# Cannot perform transaction Qt PostgreSQL

Tags: c++, database, qt, postgresql, transactions

I am trying to create simple app to communicate and control my database. I am using `PostgreSQL DBMS`. I have installed all required drivers for Linux.
I open connection to database like this

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
db.setDatabaseName(dbName);
db.setHostName(host);
db.setUserName(usr);
db.setPassword(pwd);
if (!db.open())
{
    return false;
}
```

Everything seems to work well, I can perform exec sql queries and other things. But I have problem with transaction. First time I just opened transaction calling transaction method, but didn't checked it for return value and because of this it didn't work like I expected, because of methods like commit and rollback didn't work. So in my case transaction method always returns false.
Also there is one weird thing , If I try to get last error from db object , I will get `"Driver not loaded Driver not loaded"`, but nevertheless it still works good with simple queries.

```
   QSqlQuery query;
        QSqlDriver *driver = QSqlDatabase::database().driver();
        if (driver->hasFeature(QSqlDriver::Transactions)) {
       if(db.transaction()) {
```

In this example it returns **true** for `hasFeature` but I am getting **false** in `db.transaction`.

**Note:** I am using Linux(Mint x64).

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example? Which Qt version are you using?

Comment: How did you installed driver? I assume db mustn't have any error.